# htaccess for shortened URL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a URL shortener script.
My script generates a link like `http://127.0.0.1:1337/urlshortener/v5tjp`.

`v5tjp` is a random value, generated by a script.

My script's logic is that I input an URL, then PHP takes it, generates a random value (with the length taken also from the SQL database), then inserts the long url and the short url in the database.

Where I'm stuck: I need to create a .htaccess file to redirect the visitor to redirect.php, where I have the redirect script.

This is the redirect.php file:

```
<?php

include ('connect.php');

$decode = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['decode']);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM urls WHERE short_code="$decode"';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (isset($_GET['url_token'])){
    $urlId=$_GET['url_token'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE short_code=".$urlId." LIMIT 1";
    $redirect = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($redirect)) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($redirect);
        $url = $row['long_url'];
        header('Location: http://'.$url);
    }
    echo 'Bad URL!';
    exit();

}



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$res=$row['long_url'];
header("location:".$res);

}
```

This is the .htaccess file I've made:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRle ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?url_token=$1 [L]
```

But for some reason it's not working. I'm running my script with XAMPP.

Comment: It sais that the file could not be found on the server, but I have that random value in my database...

Comment: Where did you put your .htaccess file?

Comment: In the `urlshortener` folder.

Comment: If you write some garbage at the start of htaccess, are you still getting a 404 not found, or internal server error?

Comment: Yes, same situation. I think it won't read my `.htaccess` file. I don't know why. I've checked if my `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is not commented, and it is not. It should read my file.

Comment: No, sounds like it's not being read. Check permissions on the file so that the web server can read it, and that no .htaccess in the root folder is overriding the redirect somehow.

Comment: There is no other .htaccess file anywhere in htdocs folder. What else can I try? Is it ok to have my .htaccess file inside the folder with the other files?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

You missed a 'u'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRle ^$ /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteRule ^urlshortener/(.*)$ /redirect.php?url_token=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: There was a minot typo, try it now. Also provide more details like what is the full URL you tried?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:1337/urlshortener/v5tjp`
It should redirect me to `http://google.com/`, but it won't. In my database it's associated to this URL.

Comment: Whaat? No where in your requirement I see requirement to redirect to `http://google.com/`? Please specify your requirement clearly.

Comment: btw above rule (with .htaccess & mod_rewrite enabled) should internally forward your example URL to: `/redirect.php?url_token= v5tjp`

Comment: Still not working... I'm out ouf ideas, I've been trying everything

Comment: To start with start reading my comments and try to describe your problem.

Comment: I don't understand... I've described my problem and I've been trying everything you told me to.
My problem: it seems that my XAMPP server won't read my .htaccess file.

Comment: You wrote a comment: `http://127.0.0.1:1337/urlshortener/v5tjp It should redirect me to http://google.com/` whereas in your question there is no mention of this google requirement.